# Can I prevent deleting the ios mdm profile?

Tags: ios, mdm

Can I prevent deleting the ios mdm profile?
The reference has a feature called PayloadRemovalDisallowed, but I wonder if it also applies to MDM.

I saw several posts, but I did not get the answer.

Comment: You can only prevent profile removal if the device is supervised; either using the Apple Configurator or the Device Enrolment Program

Answer (score 1):

`PayloadRemovalDisallowed` key can be set to supervised devices and it can be set to configuration profiles only. MDM Profile cannot hold this value. However if you worry about `PayloadRemovalDisallowed` key then its available only for supervised devices and you can set MDM profile unremovable through DEP itself.

From [Apple's Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf)

> OSX versions 10.10 and later honor a true value of the PayloadRemovalDisallowed key to prevent manual removal of profiles installed through an MDM server. Such profiles cannot be removed using the Profiles
>       preference pane, nor the profiles command line tool even when run as root. Only the MDM server can remove
>       such profiles. Profiles installed manually, with PayloadRemovalDisallowed set to true, can be removed
>       manually, but only by using administrative authority

Answer (score 1):

If you are enrolling your device from Apple Configurator. Then there is 31 days grace period. The reason for this is the grace period of DEP enrollment when done with Apple Configurator. So when a device previously not part of the company devices is added under the company DEP account, it allows the user to cancel this operation during this 30 day grace period. After this time has passed, both the lock screen message and the "Leave Remote Management" option will disappear from the device.